# What does "The dimmer the light the greater the scandal" mean?

Tags: phrases

I saw this in a list of quotes, but can't figure out what it means, or find where it comes from.

I've searched extensively on google, but no joy. I assume it's not very common?

Comment: Well, common sense seems to indicate that when a secret needs to be kept, little light will be shed on it, so the darker the scene, the more scandalous the secret that needs to be concealed.

Comment: @Gustavson Ahh thank you it all makes sense now. Don't know why I was so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a construction that shows up frequently in adages, using two comparatives in a row with *the* and optional commas, viz

- *the bigger, the better* = 'goodness increases as size increases'
- *the bigger they are, the harder they fall* = 'dethroning a powerful person is better than an underling'
- *the less you have, the more they pick on you* = 'it is safer to annoy the poor than the rich'

To this must be added the interpretations added from metaphors, in particular that of ***Light***. Lights can be brighter or dimmer, and our vision depends on light being available in sufficient brightness. Metaphorically, *shining light on something* means making it public and visible; it is what you do to scandals. Scandals prefer dark corners and underworlds.

Then there is the ambiguity of *great* and *scandal*. Is a scandal that never becomes public a great scandal? Or is it great only because it's been made public? This can get complex, but it's not important.

So, what it **says** is that the greatness of the scandal increases as the light diminishes in brightness. What it **means**, practically speaking, is  something nobody is likely to disagree with -- that great scandals thrive in dim circumstances. One need not rate scandals in greatness units to know that.

Answer (score 0):

from the figurative sense of **dim**:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52854?rskey=Nj4bGW&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> fig. Not clear to the mind or understanding; obscure, faint.

As in:

*With more obscurity (dimmer the light) the scandal flourished.*

Answer (score -1):

Look it up --

Dimmer

[image]

Light

[image]

Grater

[image]

Scandal

[image]